# Skype 4.3 screen sharing in group call

Tags: 14.04, skype

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Skype 4.3.37.
When I participate in Skype group call and other user share the screen, I am not able to see the screen.  If the call is not group call and between 1 to 1, I have no issues.
One of my colleague who is using Ubuntu 14.04 and skype 4.3 also have the same problem.

Any help will save my days of time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you simply not see the remote desktop contents (black window) or does Skype not change its windows as if it were _trying_ to show the remote desktop?

Comment: @BigChris, No, It is keeping the regular group call scree (Showing the photos of members).  But the person who shared the screen getting a waring message like "Some people on the group call are unable see group video.  They may need to update Skype or use a supported device".

Comment: You are using Ubuntu 14.04. According to the Microsoft/Skype website (http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/) your Ubuntu isn't supported, however, there are a few prerequisites - I'm wondering if something is missing. Have a read of the link and click to learn more about Skype for Linux.

Comment: Thank you @BigChris, I thought this is problem of Ubuntu.  Since in 14.04, Ubuntu team made some big changes to Unity.  I am facing very tough time here, since I cannot join the calls with my clients. :(  I may have to wait for next release I think.

Comment: You might have to use, say, VirtualBox and install Windows to be able to use the Skype functionality you need... sorry!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to do group video call and group screen share using Skype 4.3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/534186/unable-to-do-group-video-call-and-group-screen-share-using-skype-4-3)

Comment: I am still struggling for the alternative...  Skype release a latest version for linux.  But We cannot have call and screen share for 1 to 1 itself (not group).   Microsoft should feel shame for this.

Answer (score 12):

This does not work on Linux for the moment. See this question:
[Unable to do group video call and group screen share using Skype 4.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534186/unable-to-do-group-video-call-and-group-screen-share-using-skype-4-3?rq=1)

or this Skype forum:
http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-4-3-0-37-There-s-no-screen-sharing-and-video-chat-in-the/m-p/3558973#M10792

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft released a new version of skype and blocked all old versions that are 4.3.x or previous.  So it is mandatory to upgrade to latest version (I remember 7.x or later).

This new version still has few problems (As per my observation).  That are:

1. Group call still does not support screen share.
2. Group video call - Not working
3. Audio becomes noisy after 2 mins of call start.

Seems, #1 and #3 has been fixed in Very recent (8.x) version.  But, if you are running on Ubuntu 16.04 version, no problem.  But if you are running on higher version, then you may have to consider to run with Xorg instead of Wayland.

See these links:
[Skype and screen sharing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979799/skype-and-screen-sharing)
[How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)