# sharing screen in a group skype meeting

Tags: skype

I am trying to share my screen for a skype group call, but when I add the second one to the call, the share screen stops. I cannot share the screen for more than one people. can you help me with this? my colleagues use windows or ios.

Thanks

Comment: I think it's a limitation of the Skype for Linux. Also check this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/522282/skype-4-3-screen-sharing-in-group-call

Comment: Do u know any other program that I can use? For sharing my screen in a video conference?