# How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: xorg, wayland, 17.10

Some of my applications don't work on Ubuntu 17.10 Wayland. How can I switch back to Xorg?

Comment: Out of curiosity - which applications?

Comment: Shutter [1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/shutter/+bug/1502263), for example.

Comment: I can add x11vnc to the list

Comment: gparted does not work anymore, either, and according to this answer ( https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w ) Wayland is to blame. I found this page looking for a solution, as a system on which I can't modify partitions is pretty f'ing useless.

Comment: I can add configuring "Devices > Display Arrangement" to the list. It does not work properly in Wayland. Every time I wake my laptop I have to configure which external monitor should be on the left and which on the right - it just doesn't remember.

Comment: I've tried to install Tilda, which is my Quake-like terminal of choice, and it doesn't work because of this change. Guake has some issues as well.

Comment: Add vlc as well to that list

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen
5 years later, x11vnc, out of the box didn't work, that's when I learned I had caught the waylands on ubuntu 21. So first task now is ripping out wayland. I don't understand why the wayland folks didn't as a first step ensure that their new doodad would be transparently compatible with the previous system. I have to report that setting WaylandEnable=false in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf did eliminate wayland from memory so yay !

Answer (score 70, accepted):

When you boot your system and get to the GDM login screen you should find a cogwheel (⚙️) next to the sign in button. If you click on the cogwheel you should find an **Ubuntu on Xorg** option which will start an Xorg session instead of a Wayland session.

[image]

Comment: I don't even see that option on my machine. I just see Ubuntu on Xorg and Unity.

Comment: Wayland IS compatible with my system. I am using Wayland, but I want to switch to Xorg, because gparted doesn't work with Wayland

Comment: @Aloso Hmm... not sure what's happening, but you might want to see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w) in order to make GParted work in a Wayland session.

Comment: @pomsky I tried all the options in that other answer you linked, and none of them worked, I still can't use gparted. I found this answer from a link from that one, as I continued my search because that "answer" didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @MatthewNajmon That means you have a new question, mention clearly that you tried **all** the answers to the older question and that **all of them** failed (explain how they failed). Then I believe it won't be closed as a  duplicate. And no profanity please.

Comment: Does one selection stays chosen for further logins? Or does one have to use the cogwheel every time to login to Xorg?

Comment: @Marecky It should remember your choice for the next time. So no need to use the cogwheel every single time.

Answer (score 62):

If you wish to do it permanently, edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and uncomment the line:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

by removing the `#` in front of it.

Save the file and then on reboot you will never see the cog asking for which session to use.

**EDIT:** Apparently @doug beat me to this answer. I didn't see it earlier - It was in a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10/968265#comment1548891_966323) that was hidden initially.

Comment: Sorry, Ubuntu newb here - I don't have an /etc/gdm3 directory. Anywhere else it could be?

Comment: @MichaelKupietz what display manager are you using?
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1831388

Comment: Works like a charm. Finally making hangouts usable. On the Debian test release the file is:
`/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf`

Comment: Any way to change the default without disabling? (but still be able to pick it from the login screen cog)

Comment: this messes up the display color in my laptop. Any reason why that is, and what the resolution could be?

Comment: @CiroSantilliПутлерКапут六四事 I don't think so. Its just that it hard defaults to wayland when possible

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ idk, never experienced that by changing the above mentioned files. Maybe you changed something else accidentally.

Comment: Works like a charm on desktop with Linux Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You  may want to remove wayland session to prevent accidental logins.

<

Your package maintainers will be proud of you if you do it as follows:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/wayland-sessions/hidden
sudo dpkg-divert --rename \
      --divert /usr/share/wayland-sessions/hidden/ubuntu.desktop \
      --add /usr/share/wayland-sessions/ubuntu.desktop
```

What this does is to instruct the package manager to remember a new location for the file.  This has several advantages over the other answers:

- It guarantees a future package install/upgrade won't revert your change
- It works with other display managers (lxdm for example lists `.backup` entries)
- You can revert it easily if you change your mind with:

  `sudo dpkg-divert --rename --remove /usr/share/wayland-sessions/ubuntu.desktop`

>

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/500813/602695

Comment: One could also simply edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` & uncomment `#WaylandEnable=false` It will not be overwritten without user consent if at all

Comment: @doug Your answer will only work with gdm3 though, one may be using LightDM -as I do-, My answer will work for both LightDM and gdm3.

Answer (score 0):

May be running app like this can help? Can someone try it? Because I don't know whether that will be helpful to others.

For example you need to run app called Putty from Wayland but it doesn't work because of font called "server:fixed" doesn't exist in Wayland, or may be it doesn't available for some reason. So you can change shortcut or run it from shell this way:

```
env GDK_BACKEND=x11 putty
```

Replace putty with something that you need.
You need to set varibale exactly with env `env GDK_BACKEND=x11`, without env it will not work (for Putty at leased)

Found here:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326331/where-to-set-gdk-backend
- https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/putty/pull-request/3

Original: https://askubuntu.com/a/1402103/1586450