# Ubuntu 17.10 Cursor mirrored on second screen

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, mouse, cursor, 17.10

I have a strange issue. I got a Laptop running with two external screens. They are configured like this: (1 is the Laptop)
[image: Display Arrangement]

When I move my mouse the the left half of the screen number 2, the cursor is also visible on the bottom of screen 3. But clicking only affects screen 2. When moving the cursor to screen 3, it is not mirrored on screen 2. Here you can see a visualization. When the cursor is in the red area, it is also visible in the green area but not vise versa.

[image: Screens]

Thank you!
Jack

Comment: I have this also after upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10.

Comment: If anyone comes across link to fix, can they please post it here in the comments? Thank you!

Comment: I get this too.

Comment: @user1063287 Have you tried [switching back to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)?

Comment: same problem here, did you open a bug?

Comment: There's a [bug report at Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1728305)

Comment: Upstream bug [reported to Gnome devs](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789675)