# Ubuntu 17.10 Gparted, gksudo issue

Tags: gparted, 17.10, gksudo

[image: Terminal Screenshot]

Unable to use Gparted on 17.10. I have already tried "sudo xauth merge $HOME/.Xauthority" and with gksu and gksudo. Gksudo has another issue in Ubuntu 17.10. I am unable to enter password in the prompt that appears.

Comment: Try issuing the command `xhost si:localuser:root` - this should allow you to run both gparted and gksu.  If it works for you, you can create a startup command to run this for your sessions.

Comment: gparted worked. Thanks.  But gksu/ gksudo didn't. ```/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc:30: error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant
Error copying '/home/omkar/.Xauthority' to '/tmp/libgksu-sgKkUm': Permission denied```

Comment: You may [switch back to Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) if you wish.