# Gimp produces black screenshot after upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gimp, 17.10

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10, I am facing a serious shortcoming in gimp. The screenshots are completely black.

Most likely this is a bug, but I thought of investigating a bit just to find out if I am missing something.

The other `Screenshot` software, version 3.25.0 is working fine.

Comment: It works for me in Ubuntu 17.10 persistent live. Maybe your problem is because you have upgraded from a previous version, and there are some settings or libraries left from the previous version.

Comment: @sudodus Do you think that purging `gimp*` and then installing again will help?

Comment: You can try, maybe it is enough :-) Maybe you have to purge and reinstall something else (I don't know what it would be).

Comment: @sudodus I tried `purge` and then `autoremove` and `install`, no luck. Even rebooted my machine in between for good measures.

Comment: You can download and make a USB boot drive of Ubuntu 17.10. Boot live 'Try Ubuntu', then you can `sudo add-apt-repository universe`; `sudo apt update`; `sudo apt install gimp` and try if screenshot with gimp works in your computer. If it does, you can consider making a fresh installation instead of the upgraded system that you have now. Of course, before you start on this venture, you should **backup** all files, that you cannot afford to lose.

Comment: You would say, that this feature in gimp is not reason enough to make a fresh installation, but this version of Ubuntu is very different from the previous versions, because there is a new desktop environment, and there is Wayland instead of X. So there may be many other problems in upgraded systems, things that work in a fresh installation.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure but maybe it's an issue with Wayland. Try [switching to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10).

Comment: @pomsky Indeed, switching to an Xorg session solved the issues with gimp. Any comprehensive suggestion?