# How to make Screencast on Ubuntu 17.10 record longer than 30s?

Tags: 17.10, screencast, desktop-recording

Ubuntu Desktop Guide > Tips & tricks says that we can start and stop a screencast by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. It works. But it automatically stops at 30s.

Is there a default settings somewhere for that? Or is it a bug?

Before on Ubuntu 17.04 I used `gtk-recordmydesktop` but now it won't launch. I tried `simplescreenrecorder` and `vokoscreen` but for some reason the screen goes black in the result file. The cursor is visible though.

Comment: You can try [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/)

Comment: @pomsky Hey simplescreenrecorder and vokoscreen work after I switched to Xorg. When I switched again to Wayland it keeps working. The built-in Screencast still doesn't work, but it's fine now. Thanks!

Comment: @pomsky I asked 7 hours earlier though (- . -)

Comment: @YasminZulfatiYusrina The idea was to create a more general Q&A and direct all the new questions similar to this to that one. But you're right, maybe you should just link the other question instead of marking it as  a duplicate.

Comment: Related to: [Why some of my screen-recording/capturing applications (or app features) are not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966779/why-some-of-my-screen-recording-capturing-applications-or-app-features-are-not)

Comment: @YasminZulfatiYusrina See if this helps: https://askubuntu.com/a/967989/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 17.10 by default uses Wayland server. Many application which are not yet completely compatible with Wayland may fail to work under a  Wayland session.

You may try to [switch to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) to make the applications work again.

Answer (score 12):

One can adjust the recording time via gsettings.

Suppose one wants 1 minute of recording time:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys max-screencast-length 60
```

sets the recording time to 60 seconds.

You can also set this to 0, to turn off the auto-stop behavior entirely. Then press Ctrl + Alt + Shift + R again to stop it manually.