# gparted won't start under ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gparted, 17.10

I have been using gparted for years under any ubuntu version.
gparted won't start under ubuntu 17.10. Is this a bug of ubuntu 17.10?

Answer (score 23):

It is known bug of Wayland (I read it as "high security is better than user comfort" and I do not support developer's logic).
It was already reported (see [bug 1652282](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gparted/+bug/1652282)).
Other root applications are broken on Wayland too (see [bug 1713313](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713313) and [bug 1713311](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713311)
).

You should switch to "Ubuntu on Xorg" session for such applications.

For applications which use su-to-root and pkexec you may want to add this code to `/etc/xdg/autostart/xhost.desktop` (see [my comment at launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/backintime/+bug/1713313/comments/3)) at your own risk with command below:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/xdg/autostart/xhost.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=xhost
Comment=Fix graphical root applications
Exec="xhost +si:localuser:root"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
EOF
```

---

If you do not want permanent solution, you may use @ravery's method:

> just type `xhost +si:localuser:root` in the terminal before launching gparted

Comment: Too complicated for me. I don't know Wayland neither do I know how to switch to "Ubuntu on Xorg". Can you recommend another program to work with partitions under 17.10?

Comment: @Ulrich -- just type `xhost +si:localuser:root` in the terminal before launching gparted

Comment: @Ulrich, you can choose x11 or wayland when you log into Ubuntu by clicking on the circular icon on the login page.

Comment: @Ulrich https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10

Comment: Ravery's comment works, it should be added as an answer

Comment: @ravery 's solution works. follow that.