# How to determine gnome-terminal window ID in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: gnome-terminal, 17.10

In Ubuntu 17.04 I could use `wmctrl` to switch to a gnome-terminal window with given window ID:

```
wmctrl -ia $gnome_term_winid
```

The window ID of a given `gnome-terminal` could also be displayed from the terminal by typing:

```
echo $WINDOWID
```

After upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10, this is no longer the case. First, `echo $WINDOWID` gives nothing, and also `wmctrl -lx` does not show any `gnome-terminal` windows.

Comment: Thanks, I reported [bug 1725991 on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1725991) about that.

Answer (score 10):

`wmctrl` doesn't work properly in a Wayland session as controlling windows is against Wayland's security policy.

`wmctrl` may work with the application windows running under the XWayland compatibility layer (for example Firefox). But `gnome-terminal` is an official GNOME app which doesn't run under XWayland so it fails.

You may try to [switch to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) as a workaround.

Comment: There are some proposed protocols to support it in general way in wayland, but not one is working on it yet. Really is a shame, i can not concidered a wayland protocol ready to go on linux until this problem will not be resolved. A lot of apps are not working because of this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45465016/how-do-i-get-the-active-window-on-gnome-wayland/46557325