# VLC crash on Ubuntu 17.10 Screen Freezes

Tags: sound, video, vlc, 17.10

2days ago I upgraded my Ubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10, all the process went fine and the upgrade was successful. But after some few hours I played a .mp4 video with vlc players the video plays on full screen for 3 to 4 seconds and freeze the screen, audio keep playing but the video stopped and the keyboard and mouse stops responding, the only way to get out of this is to force shutdown the computer and restart it. Happens every times with Ubuntu 17.10 never experience the problem with 17.04. How to get out of this am a vlc fan.

Comment: Are you in a Wayland session? If so try to switch to an Xorg session and see if it continues crashing: https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10

Comment: I'm having the same problem, also occurs with SMPlayer, haven't tried gnome video player (not sure which package contains h264 codec)

Comment: This is fixed in VLC 3.0 which is not released yet (https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/17829)

Comment: While a fix is released the best solution is probably to disable the full screen controls. The option is in preferences -> show settings all -> Interface -> Main Interfaces -> Qt -> Show a controller in fullscreen mode. There are shortcuts for almost everything anyway. The interface becomes responsive again after the video ends too, which is not good enough for anything long.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem when playing full screen videos in VLC. I [switched to XORG](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the problem did not re-occur.

Comment: Am experiencing the problem with xorg as well, but the xorg last very long than Wayland. Am not using full screen mode for now while we wait for VLC version 3.

Comment: I was also experiencing basically an identical issue and switching to xorg has so far been the fix.