# Ubuntu 17.10 display glitch with AMD Radeon RX480

Tags: xorg, display, wayland, amdgpu

After a fresh Ubuntu 17.10 installation, my screen looks like this:

[image: weird noisy glitchy ubuntu screen]

I cannot read a single character on the screen because of that weird screen noise. Also, my screen's resolution is 2560*1080 but I only get 1920*1080 input signal to my monitor, and the original content of the the display gets shrunk into that smaller resolution.

I can solve this by [switching back to Xorg from Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/a/968265/543070).

But I would like to use Wayland if possible because its faster. Thank You!

*Edit*: my VGA: **AMD Radeon RX480** driver is **amdgpu** and my monitor is **LG25UP** and connected with HDMI to my VGA.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and also include details about how the monitor is connected (DisplayPort, HDMI, DVI, VGA, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `mesa` driver instead of `amdgpu`. I'm a Fedora user with your same rx480, and with mesa on Wayland I have very good performance.

Comment: This is a fresh install, i dont have previous kernels.