# Navigation with keyboard on the Panel notification area in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, panel, gnome-shell, notification-area

I can't navigate with keys (like in Unity) in the right Panel notification area in Ubuntu 17.10. I can do it with arrow keys in the message tray and in calendar, but not in the menu with volume and brightness.

[image: Right Top Bar]

I checked the wiki at https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-nav.html, but nothing works.

Any idea to do it?

Comment: How did you get there? ctrl+alt+tab and then "Topbar"?

Comment: I'm able to get to the Top Bar, the problem is to navigate in the right menu (showed in the picture above) through arrows key.

Comment: Down arrow works for me!

Comment: @pomsky on Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: Yep, down arrow to go to options. Left & right arrow to decrease/increase volume/brightness.

Comment: @pomsky it's strange, mine not works.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue on my Ubuntu 17.10. This could be because of Wayland display server. Switching to Xorg, solved the issue for me.

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) to switch from Wayland to Xorg.