# Ubuntu 17.10 freezes frequently

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hardware, 17.10

I have a XPS 15 (9550) running Ubuntu 17.10 that occasionally freezes with only the mouse cursor movable. I have to force reboot the system when it happens. When I try to switch tty these messages appears on the screen (https://pasteboard.co/GRJaXYe.jpg).

Previously I have a Windows partition on the same laptop that has the same symptom that has been fixed by using an alternate driver for the nvme ssd (Toshiba THNSN5512GPU7) as apparently this was a known issue for this laptop running on this type of ssd on Windows. I do not see any solution yet for linux so please help me out as I ran out of options other than swapping the ssd.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and It is mostly because of Wayland display server.

So for now, you can just switch to Xorg.

Go through this: [How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: Thanks but I am already running on Xorg instead of wayland

Comment: Had the same issue with constant micro freezing, switching to Xorg solved it for me so far.