# 17.10 Crash when playing video

Tags: video, vlc, crash

I recently found myself enjoying Ubuntu & I updated to 17.10. Although I found a bug that is frustrating. When I play a video with vlc or other video player after a while my pc crashes. My graphics card is a Radeon HD6870 & I did not have any issue a few days ago with Linux Mint 18.2 that I was using.

Can you advise my anything or I should wait for an update. I found some questions regarding playing video with vlc but I did not occur only with vlc.

Please help me. I really like Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Sorry nocogwheel for me...

Comment: I tested it and I am in XORG

Answer (score 0):

inside, in all settings, you must find FFmpeg decoder and switch off hardware acceleration. All work fine. CPU - 3-4% loading. (i5 3570/Nvidia 1050Ti/8G DDR3/Asus Z77-V-Pro/Linux Mint 18.3 Cinn 64bit). Try. Its easy.

OLEG