# Color Picker function in many applications doesn't work in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, gimp, wayland, geany

Color Picker function in Gimp, Geany or Gpick doesn't work in Ubuntu 17.10.

Are there any known workarounds for this problem?

Comment: See also: [Is there a colour picker that works with Wayland or XWayland?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/320070/3000)

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with the default Wayland session in Ubuntu 17.10, it seems this feature is not implemented yet (see this [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=780375)).

As a workaround you may [switch back to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10).