# 17.10 gnome-terminal resize info with CompizConfig Settings Manager

Tags: unity, compiz, gnome-terminal, 17.10, tooltip

From a time even far before Ubuntu 13.04, there was always a method, when one resized Gnome Terminal, to see an immediate visual tooltip which showed what length and width you were resizing Gnome terminal to.

This used to be the default with Ubuntu, then it was made optional.  When it became optional, the way to launch it would be to launch  CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm) and have "resize info" enabled.

I just upgraded to 17.10 today (I waited several weeks to upgrade since I was burned by bug #1674838 crashing my machine every day earlier this year, and had to wait several weeks for a fix, and figured this time I would wait a few weeks for things to settle down).  I waited several weeks because I was hit with bug #1674838 earlier this year, and dreaded what bugs and pulled features I would encounter this time around.

I enabled resize info for all windows in ccsm, but don't see the tool tip for Gnome Terminal any more.  Has the method of doing this changed?  Or has this useful feature which Ubuntu had since before 13.04 just been tossed into the dustbin?  My laptop runs Ubuntu and still has this tooltip running, and now I dread the idea of upgrading it to 17.10.

Is there a way to turn this on, or has the feature been discarded after existing for years?

Also, I don't really have the time to do it, but I have had patches applied to Gnome and fd.o projects before...if this feature has been tossed, what should I target to program it back in, just for myself if need be?

Comment: Yes I switched from Wayland to Xorg and it's back to working.  That gets it working for me for now, thanks!

Comment: Glad to know that! I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Wayland specific issue (see this [bug report for Fedora](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1306260)).

As a workaround you may [switch back to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) for now.

Answer (score 0):

This has bothered me for several versions of Ubuntu, currently on 17.10. I got motivated to find a workaround because I'm now switching between 80-column and 100-column formatted code.

I don't want to switch to Xorg. So my solution is to run this command inside the Gnome Terminal when I want to resize:

```
$ watch stty size
```

then use the mouse to resize. The size information updates instantly as the mouse moves, not delayed by 2 seconds. (It looks like the 'watch' command traps the SIGWCH signal generated by the mouse resize and reruns the 'stty' command.)