# How do I close Discord in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

When I click `X` or use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close Discord, the application disappears from the taskbar. But I'm still online, receiving messages and notifications in Ubuntu when new messages arrive.

So how do I actually **close** the application? I'd rather not have to use the terminal every time I want to close it. (Not bashing the terminal, but I feel I shouldn't have to use it for this)

Comment: Discord is an application that stays open as background application with a panel icon. Not sure how this looks in new Gnome, but under Unity you would have a Discord icon in your panel (top bar). Clicking on that should show you a menu allowing to quit it.

Comment: You're right. But there's no such icon in the top bar now (in GNOME), maybe the icon is accessed somewhere else now

Comment: As purely temporary solution. Could you use xkill _Alt+F2 and type xkill_ then you have cursor as X and kill it before you clinck on x

Comment: @NexusStar A better similar workaround would probably be to run something like `killall discord` through Alt-F2...

Comment: @pomsky Installing TopIcons Plus was a great solution, thanks!

Comment: @NexusStart, @ByteCommander: Using `xkill` or `killall discord` with the `ALT-F2` doesnt work. These commands need sudo privileges.

Comment: Neither of these two commands do require `sudo`, especially for `xkill` it makes no sense to run that with elevated privileges - why do you think so? If it doesn't work, the reason might be that the Discord background app has a different name.

Comment: Whoops, my bad! Tried both commands in the `ALT-F2` dialog but nothing happened. Wrongly assumed it needed sudo privileges. Sorry.

Comment: Are you in a default Wayland session (instead of Xorg)? If so, probably that's the reason.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I start my computer, Ubuntu boots and I log in to my user. I'm oblivious to what kind of session that is

Comment: @gromit190 You can check your current session by running `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and to switch to Xorg: https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10 but if everything else is working fine for you, no need to do the switching.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Discord stays open as a background application with a system tray icon. The "Ubuntu appindicators" extension which is responsible for showing these icons, fails to show many app icons, electron based apps especially.

You may install [TopIcons Plus extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/) to show the icon for Discord.

Comment: Too bad, I'm having the exactly same problem with Discord but this extension doesn't seem to be actively maintained anymore: https://github.com/phocean/TopIcons-plus/issues/91

Comment: @KarthicRaghupathi The extension was updated very recently (most probably by a new maintainer) and now officially supports up to GNOME v3.30: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/. Also there's another fork: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1497/topicons-redux/

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for the update. I will look into this again.

Comment: TopIcons+ is no longer maintained. I would suggest the KStatusNotifierItem: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/

Comment: @Jamie Indeed, but Ubuntu comes with an extension called '[Ubuntu Appindicators](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1301/ubuntu-appindicators/)' (pre-installed  and activated by default), which is a fork of the one you mentioned. If the pre-installed one is not working for some specific app(s), there is a high chance that KStatusNotifierItem would also not work.

Answer (score 38):

I don't know why nobody is aware this shortcut but here it is: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> shuts Discord down.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, where is it documented? 
Glad it works as desired on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This still works (Ubuntu 20.04 in 2022 here), probably on ANY window manager ! (i3 / regolith here)

Comment: Still works on Ubuntu 22.04 May 2022.

Answer (score 18):

- Click on the Cog icon(⚙️) in Left bottom to open User Settings.

  [image: 1]
- Go to Linux Settings and disable *"Minimise to Tray"*.

  [image: 2]
- Click on "X" to close the app.
- To check whether app is running or not, look for "Discord" in System Monitor, or open a terminal and run

  ```
  ps aux | grep discord
  ```

  The output will show that no Discord process running now.

Comment: This works as advertised on Pop!_OS.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.