# "Desktop" folder disappeared from Nautilus side bar

Tags: nautilus, 17.10

On my Nautilus in Ubuntu 17.10, Desktop icon/link on side bar disappeared. How could I restore it?

I've tried to edit `user-dirs.dirs` file without any success. The strange thing is the difference between nautilus side bar and dialog "open file" from application (e.g. Chrome)

[image]

Comment: Yes I have rebooted

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it's a Wayland-only issue. If you [switch to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) "Desktop" should be there.

Comment: I confirm that I have the issue with wayland

Comment: This workaround may be a temporary fix: Visit Desktop and bookmark it.