# Bookmark desktop in Nautilus on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: nautilus, 17.10

I noticed that, in Ubuntu 17.10, Nautilus has a slightly weird selection of "places" in the left side-pane - at least for my taste (trash can is there, but Desktop isn't...). However, as far as I can tell, there is no way to customize this, other than to edit the source code and recompile. So, I would at least like to bookmark the Desktop, but the "Bookmark current location" option is inactive, when I open the Desktop in Nautilus.

Is this normal, or is this just a problem with my installation? If it's normal, does anyone have an idea how to bookmark the Desktop anyway?

Comment: I believe it's a Wayland-only issue. If you [switch to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) Desktop should be there in "places" as expected. (Same as [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976255/desktop-disappeared-from-nautilus-side-bar) actually.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, you were correct. I decided to switch back to Wayland anyway, because I have a HiDPI screen, and on 17.10/Xorg, you can't yet choose a screen scaling other than 100% or 200% :D.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with 17.10 is that if you take the Desktop icon from the right hand pane of Nautilus and drag it to the lower bookmark pane, it will create a bookmark for it there. You don't seem to be able to create a bookmark in the upper bookmark area.

I store all my data in a Dropbox folder.  I therefore deleted built in folders such as Documents and Videos, as they contained nothing.  Their icons continued to remain in the upper bookmarks area, and the secondary click "Remove" function was greyed out.  However after I rebooted, the system seemed to become aware that the icons for Documents etc. were pointing at folders which no longer existed.  After a reboot, the "Remove" function worked.