# Redshift couldn't be initialized after upgrading from Ubuntu 17.04 to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, redshift

After upgrading from Ubuntu 17.04 to Ubuntu 17.10 Artful Aardvark, Redshift didn't autostart. Then I tried to initialize Redshift by running `sudo redshift` but it produced this:

```
Trying location provider `geoclue2'...
Using provider `geoclue2'.
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key`RANDR Query Version' returned error -1
Initialization of randr failed.
Trying next method...
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyX request failed: XOpenDisplay
Initialization of vidmode failed.
Trying next method...
No more methods to try.
```

I've searched this error on Google but no results were found. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redshift [doesn't work in the default Wayland session](https://bugs.launchpad.net/redshift/+bug/1431645) yet. You can do any of the following.

- [Switch to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) from  Wayland.
- Use the built-in "*Night Light*" feature to be found under *Settings > Devices > Displays*.