# Login loop on Ubuntu 17.10, many mentions of dbus-update-activation-environment in xession-errors

Tags: permissions, login

Ubuntu 17.10. Everytime I login with the right password, it gets back to the login screen. But `startx` can work.

I've noticed that this problem has existed for a long time, and actually tried

1. `chmod`/`chown` to `.Xauthority`, `.ICEauthority`
2. `sudo chmod a+wt /tmp`
3. don't have nvidia drivers (I think)

Also, if no method can work, is it possible to get the data from `Access-Your-Private-Data` without typing passphrase ? I only have my password.

The main content of `xsession-errors` is this:

```
Xsession: X session started for root at Mon Nov 20 21:29:35 PST 2017
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:2
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/my_name/.Xauthority
localuser:root being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
gpgconf: warning: can not open config file /home/my_name/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf: No such file or directory
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: systemd --user not found, ignoring --systemd argument
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_GID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MAIL=/var/mail/root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANGUAGE=zh_CN:zh
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=rootdbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/my_name
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT4_IM_MODULE=fcitx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MONETARY=en_CA.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-j22G1Z3FmJ,guid=0064f6bf6084b5499e918d075a13b9bf
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_UID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting TERM=linux
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USERNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting WINDOWPATH=5
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK2_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_ADDRESS=en_CA.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:2
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TELEPHONE=en_CA.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/my_name/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/startx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NAME=en_CA.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SUDO_USER=my_name
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_CA.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/my_name/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/my_name
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NUMERIC=en_CA.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_PAPER=en_CA.UTF-8
```

Comment: Possibly:  https://askubuntu.com/a/961345/231142  I am not 100% sure but maybe Wayland is loading and not xorg?

Comment: @Terrance Tried login through Xorg and Unity, they do not work : (

Comment: Darn!  Wish I had 17.10 installed to duplicate your issue.   I am one that always sticks to the LTS releases for stability.  I guess I can try a VM, but unfortunately that will not reproduce if the NVIDIA driver / card is causing this issue.  Hopefully someone might have stumbled across this before and knows how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a little be too late, but i just met the same problem, according to :
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1369216,

I just dkms my nvidia driver, then it's worked, it's something like:

```
sudo dkms install -k 4.10.0-11-generic -m nvidia-378/378.13
```

Comment: Thx. The situation on me is kinda different since my GPU is intel. But after receiving one of the Ubuntu official update, the problem just gone.