# How to get xbindkeysrc working on wayland?

Tags: 17.10, wayland

I recently bought a mx master and want to get the keybindings working ubuntu 17.10 wayland, but I've found that that do not work.

Is there a workaround or another solution?

Comment: Workaround is to use Xorg: https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10?rq=1

Comment: Doesn't work. :(