# Screenshot button not working in 17.10 Unity

Tags: unity, 17.10, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

First, have searched and read many similar questions on here and they do not seem to be the same, they are either 14.X or for vanilla Gnome. This is 17.10 Unity.

The situation:

- Upgraded two computers to 17.10
- Switched both back to Unity for several reasons, screenshots being one of them
- On one computer, screenshot app works as usual, especially Shift+Print I use a lot
- On the other, the shortcuts do nothing. In preferences, they are set as they should, and I can press Print there so the keyboard is working
- I can invoke gnome-screenshot manually

So, for some reason, on one computer the Print shortcuts just do nothing while everything does seem to be in place and a similar installation does work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wayland (default in 17.10) breaks many keyboard shortcuts, have you tried switching back to Xorg ?

Comment: @Hannibal what would be the easiest way to do that? I don't think that's it, since the other computer still works, but I am looking for any clues.

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/ and https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10

Comment: I use x.org and also have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround

Install *Compiz Config Manager* using:

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins
```

Open *Compiz Config Manager*, go to *Commands* module in the *General Section* and on *Commands* tab set some command line, e. g. "Command line 15" to `/usr/bin/gnome-screenshot`.

On Keyboard hotkeys tab specify <kbd>PrintScr</kbd> hotkey for "run command 15".

I also tried to add `/usr/bin/gnome-screenshot -w` for capturing window, but looks like 17.10 doesn't accept <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScr</kbd> as hotkey.