# Cursor appears in both monitors after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: 17.10, cursor, multiple-monitors

I've just upgraded to 17.10 and I have a dual monitor setup. One is my laptop's and the other is set on the left of it in portrait mode (this one is flagged as the primary).

The problem is that if I move the mouse pointer along the top left corner of the laptop's monitor, it shows also in the bottom left corner of the other monitor but it moves differently from the cursor in the laptop (left->right turns into up->down, up->down turns into right->left... and so on)

Any clues on this?
Thanks

Comment: Is this a Wayland-only issue? What happens if you [switch to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)?

Comment: It only happens with Wayland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's an issue with Wayland (see the [Fedora bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1513160) for example) which is the default session in Ubuntu 17.10.

As a temporary workaround you may [switch back to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10).