# VLC's "always on top" doesn't work in 17.10

Tags: 17.10, vlc

Using VLC repo version 2.2.6-6, default Desktop on laptop.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's due to Wayland's security policy. What happens if you [switch to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)?

Comment: @pomsky happens the same, tested it in  a VM with 2.2.6 and in my main machine with 3.0.0 daily-master.

Comment: You will note that right clicking on the vlc title bar and selecting 'Always on top' does actually work but only for each vlc session...