# Problems with 17.10: Blender, Atom, and other programs

Tags: graphics, mouse, 17.10, menu

Ever since installing Ubuntu 17.10 I've had issues. The most dramatic is in Blender, the panels, (for example, the text editor,) reverts to the previous version after editing when moving the mouse cursor to another panel. In other words, I can't see the text I just edited, I see the unedited text, even though the text has changed.

So when I move the mouse around all the different panels are flashing back and forth between most recent and last recent. Other programs like Atom and KolourPaint have completely lost their menu options like Save, Save As, etc.

Is there something universally wrong with 17.10 that can be tweaked, or does everything need debugging, in which case can I restore a previous version of Ubuntu? Both 14 and 16 version worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I think it's got something to do with the default Wayland session. [Switch to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) and see what happens.

Comment: @pomsky I think so too, I have Atom and Blender running on my 17.10 and no problems at all. (running pure Xorg)

Comment: This didn't work. I switched between Ubuntu and Ubuntu Xorg several times to be sure. I even tried Unity, which I didn't even know I had. I posted a video capture: https://youtu.be/_Ki3RJLQyE4 -- and thanks for the edit @NIMISHAN

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you figured it out or not, but for others who may be looking for a fix, I have the same exact issue.  Searching around through Google, I was able to find [this thread](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100740) which seems to indicate it's an issue with Blender and XWayland (I don't fully understand the issue though)

After a bit more searching I found [this question / solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69827/bug-with-blender-the-ui-to-be-more-specific-weird-stuttering-and-glitches) for a little different problem.

Basically, in Blender, go to File -> User Preferences -> System and set Window Draw Method to Triple Buffer.  So far it's working pretty good for me.

Note: I'm using and AMD Radeon HD 7950 with the open source driver.