# Ubuntu Weird Freeze

Tags: vlc, freeze, crash, lazarus

So I've been using Ubuntu for a while,and on 17.10 version I have strange bug,or crash,where my PC stops working,screen freezes(and sound is still there,if I'm listening to song,the song would continue in background).It only happens when I'm using Lazarus and VLC player.When I'm using Code::Blocks or Godot it works normally and never crashes.Please help me cause its getting really weird.
Note:VLC is more important fix then Lazarus,but on Lazarus it happens only when i type,and on VLC it happens only when I'm rewinging movie

Comment: You can try this suggested solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10?noredirect=1&lq=1