# Touchpad doesn't work properly

Tags: touchpad

My Synaptics touchpad doesn't work properly. My cursor jumps around and that is annoying. I have Ubuntu 17.10. What can I do?
Here is my xinput output

```
xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:13                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:13              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ xwayland-keyboard:13                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: There is a bug report on this problem which occurs on some 17.10 installations.  Can you append the output of the command `xinput list` to your question, please.

Comment: I see that you are using wayland.  Would you login using xorg instead, and see if the problem remains there? [https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: The bug report that I mentioned is located at [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1733032](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1733032)

Comment: It works now and xinput identifies my touchpad. But will it change in my next session?

Comment: It should remain using xorg instead of wayland as the display manager.  My unserstanding (limited) is that xorg will again be the default in 18.04.  My particular problem is in conjunction with a second touch device, and the disable-while-typing feature.