# Add "Computer" item to Nautilus sidebar on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: nautilus

On Ubuntu 17.10 there's no longer link to root partition in sidebar, called "Computer" on earlier Ubuntu versions.
Is there any way to add "Computer" item to Nautilus sidebar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll find "Computer" under "*Other locations*" at the bottom of the sidebar.

[image]

Once you have opened "Computer" (`/`) you can bookmark the location by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to make it always present in the sidebar.

Comment: Better than nothing. A shame there isn't a `gsettings` toggle somewhere.

Comment: Bookmarking, of course. Who had thought that bookmarking directory would put it in sidebar? And I can rename it too. Thanks!

Comment: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>doesn't work in my case and the button **Bookmark this location** is greyed out.

Comment: @PierreFrançois Strange! Try [switching back to Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) from Wayland.