# Proper Install Tablet WACOM Intuos Pen&Touch CTH-480 on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, gnome, 17.10, wacom, wayland

I installed newest version of Ubuntu (17.10 with default gnome,  I think) and I have troubles with tablet wacom CTH-480

First I see two cursors - one is moving, while I'm moving mouse, second is connected to Wacom.

When I try use Gimp the wacom cursor mysteriusly dissapperars. Under Windows (7,8 and 10) I just install this and everything works fine.
I tried to use some magic spells in "code" box begin with

```
    "sudo do something",
```

but it doesnt help.

Ubuntu 17 have bulit in wacom drivers and configuration, but it is not works fine. Of course it can work as a mouse substidtute, but not as a real wacom tablet for designer.

Can somebody write what is going on? Many times I saw tutorials with phrase write this, next write that, but nobody writes what am I doing writing this and why I should do that. 
I would like to get the fishing rod, instead of getting the fish.

I could use Windows (I have 2 operating systems on computer), but software like kiCAD or Blender works much faster on Linux.

Thank you in advance, 
Mirek

Answer (score 0):

The second cursor means you are using Wayland (the default). If you want to use the Wacom tablet on 17.10 you should switch to Xorg.

See this question for how to do this:

[How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)