# Ubuntu 17.10 - XWrapper.config missing

Tags: 17.10, xrdp, rdp

I have installed Ubuntu 17.10. I'm trying to RDP onto Ubuntu by following this tutorial. http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=11336

I don't seem to be able to find Xwrapper.config in /etc/X11/. It just doesn't exist.

Does anyone know how I might be able to get this file? or why it might not be on my computer?

Answer (score 2):

17.10 by default uses Wayland as the default display server rather than the legacy X.Org server. This may explain why you can't find  Xwrapper.config in /etc/X11/. You may find it there if you've gone so far as to [switch from Wayland back to Xorg.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) Otherwise I wouldn't expect to find it. The file in question is just a text configuration file that ou can create yourself if need be. More information on that is [here.](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-Xwrapper.config/)

Sources:

[How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)

https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-Xwrapper.config/

Answer (score 1):

You may try installing:

```
xserver-xorg-legacy
```

I believe it has that file, works on 18.04