# Drag-and-dropping files not working in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: files, 17.10, drag-and-drop

I recently upgraded to 17.10 from 16.10, and I'm experiencing an annoying problem:

I CAN'T drag and drop files. When I select files and then hold to drag, it behaves as though I'm re-selecting and doesn't drag the files like it did in 16.10.

Also, ctrl- and shift- selecting no longer work the way they used to, shift now selects from the FIRST file selected rather than the LAST file I selected.

I don't know if these are OS bugs or if there's an easy solution.

PLEASE HELP. I don't want to have to re-install 16.10

Comment: Could you record a short  screencast (shift+ctrl+alt+r) and show us the issue? Also this might be a Wayland-only issue, try to [switch to X](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) and see what happens there.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like Wayland was the problem. Running on Xorg now and the problem's gone....

Comment: @pomsky: How exactly does recording a short screencast work? It [creates 0-byte files for me](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1810222).

Comment: @pomsky: Yes. Is there a known issue with recording screencasts on dual-monitor configurations?

Comment: @DanDascalescu Yeah, if I remember correctly it happens with extended monitors, only creates empty files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1704765) with Wayland.

As a workaround you may switch back to Xorg following this Q&A: [How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)

Answer (score 0):

open terminal

```
    gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences use-experimental-views false
```