# Clipboard only working within same window

Tags: gnome, 17.10, clipboard, wayland

I've recently installed Ubuntu 17.10, and I've bumped into a strange, and incredibly frustrating issue: I seem to have a clipboard *per window*, rather than globally. I'm having to drag text between windows to copy and paste. And it's not even a consistent issue - I can copy one time fine, then another time it will just paste what I last copied in that window.
I'm totally stumped, so thank you for your time!

Comment: Maybe a Wayland-only issue, try [switching to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10).

Comment: That's a major bug. And it is unknown too. As told by pomsky, switching to Xorg may solve the problem. Here is how: 1. Log out of your account, 2. Click the gear icon, 3. Select Ubuntu on Xorg, 4. Enter your password and login. Tell if the issue is in Xorg session too.