# Special HP Printer Driver

Tags: printing

I have a HP MFP127fw.  It's "supported" by Ubuntu 17.10 - except print jobs will not release from the print que because a special copywrited driver for HP is not installed.

I went through this with 16.10 and had to install a small HP driver that I found with Synaptic.  Then the jobs would release. It isn't part of HPLIPS.

Apparently Ubuntu 17,10 version doesn't run synaptic due to Wayland.  Where can I find this driver?

Comment: if you know name of the driver package you can search for it in repo  `apt-cache search package`

Answer (score 3):

Install `hplip-gui` package with `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui` and add your MFP from here.

According to HP page HP LaserJet Pro MFP m127fw [is fully supported](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index).

Do not forget to install HP Driver plug-in with `hp-plugin`.

Comment: as Norbert crucially points out, you need the plug-in .. as HP advise https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index

Comment: Thanks for the help. I needed the HPLIP GUI as well as HPLIP and the special driver plug-in had to be installed separately as instructed above.  Did both things and now everything works well.

Answer (score 2):

> Apparently Ubuntu 17,10 version doesn't run synaptic due to Wayland. Where can I find this driver?

Log into 17.10 with xorg (see [How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)  ), install synaptic, find the package and then reboot and install it with Wayland. Or keep using xorg. We are switching back to xorg with 18.04 anyways.

You need [hplip 3.13](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/binaryplugintable) so nothing special there (even 14.04 already has 3.14; 17.10 has 3.16). HP claims full support so your problem should be unrelated to any extra driver you should need. Same from the [hplip update for 3.13](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/hplip-3-13-11-released-new-printers-support/): no mention about needing anything special.

Are you sure the releasing of the printer queue is not a permission/configuration problem? Because that seems more likely to me. When you do `lpstat -o` and then `cancel {printer-job-id}` or even `sudo cancel {printer-job-id}` what does it say?  If you want to investigate that specific part of your system feel free to create a new question with a description of it and the results of the cancel command :)