# UBUNTU 18.04 and scanner

Tags: 18.04, scanner

I have a Laserjet M1217nfw MFP. Worked fine until I loaded 18.04. Now the printer works, but the scanner stays dead.

Comment: According to [HPLIP page](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) you need to install *Driver plugin* (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1000506/66509) for details).