# Using xset dpms force off on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: xorg, 17.10

I used to be able to turn off the laptop screen by running `xset dpms force off`.  However now that I have upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10 this is the result:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
 Major opcode of failed request:  147 (DPMS)
 Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (DPMSForceLevel)
 Serial number of failed request:  12
 Current serial number in output stream:  14
```

Comment: are you running Xorg or Wayland.  Wayland is default on 17.10 (unless your hardware would strain), and `xset` is for Xorg & not wayland.

Comment: Try [switching back to Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10).

Comment: Is there a similar command for Wayland?  I'm using whatever Ubuntu 17.10 comes with ....