# Ubuntu 17.10 - Mouse not showing in xinput

Tags: mouse, 17.10, xinput

I have an Evoluent Vertical Mouse 4 which I've used  on Ubuntu 16, remapping keys with xinput without issue, but in 17.10, the mouse does not show under `xinput` list. This is a wired mouse plugged directly into the PC.

Here is the output for `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:14                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:14              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:14                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The mouse does show under `lsusb` though:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1a7c:0191 Evoluent VerticalMouse 4
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I tried remapping the keys for devices 4,6 and 7 from the xinput, and that remaps my keys in some places only (chrome, firefox, desktop), but not in  others (terminal, files, etc.), no idea why it would do that.

Please advise.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a mouse that occasionally stops working after suspend.  Here's what I've found so far:

1. `lsusb` shows it, `xinput` doesn't.
2. The mouse works fine.  `ll /dev/input/by-id` followed by `od < /dev/input/mouseN` where `N` is from the output of the `ll` and moving the mouse in question generated `od` output.
3. Looking at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, I found:

   ```
   [247871.760] (EE) Too many input devices. Ignoring PixArt Gaming Mouse
   ```

so that would be the culprit.  I don't know what the limit is, but I do have a USB camera and an external microphone also on the hub (attached to my monitor).

And reordering the plugs in the hub just fixed it.  I don't know if it's coincidental or it is a real workaround; I'll try to add or edit this if/when there's new info.  I'd imagine that X should allow a longer list of input devices, but if this is a real workaround, it's tolerable.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1564894 appears to be the issue tracking this.

Apparently it has to do with too many entries in `/sys/class/input` that are dangling, rather than real devices, but unfortunately one cannot remove the entries from userspace.  Just have to wait for the 4.18 kernel, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with Wayland server. Changing Wayland to Xorg might be help full.

[How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) this will help to change Wayland to Xorg