# Want to disable Track stick, but doesn't show up in Xinput

Tags: touchpad, xinput

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 (from 16.04 TLS). I've had problems with my track stick since I own this laptop (Toshiba Portège): the pointer moves all over the screen when it's not disabled. Previously I would fix this by disabling the device

```
xinput disable <device number>
```

However, the pointer stick doesn't show up in the list when I run `xinput`. Neither does my touchpad, by the way.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:13                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:13              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ xwayland-keyboard:13                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Someone else had a similar question, which unfortunately has not been answered: [Ubuntu 17.10 - Mouse not showing in xinput](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001044/ubuntu-17-10-mouse-not-showing-in-xinput)

So my question would be: does anyone know an alternative solution to disabling the track stick without xinput?

Thanks in advance!