# Synaptic Packager Manager won't open

Tags: package-management, synaptic, zotero

Running Ubuntu 17.10. Installed Synaptic Package Manager through Terminal, but it won't open -- just asks for my password and then immediately closes. Ultimately I'm trying to use it to install Zotero 5.0, so alternative routes to that are also welcome. Downloading through Zotero website leaves me with a desktop configuration file that's functional but buried in several layers of folders, and attempting to do it through a web-based `curl` yielded nothing at all.

Attempted running `synaptic-pkexec` and it produced an error message: "No Protocol specified. Tried `synaptic`  and it returned "Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged. Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: Can you try launching `synaptic-pkexec` or `synaptic` (will start without elevated permissions -> read-only) from the terminal? Do any error messages appear then?

Comment: Error messages: `synaptic-pkexec` says "No protocol Specified" and "Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused"
`synaptic` comes up with "Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged. Segmentation fault (core dumped"

Comment: This is weird. Maybe try `sudo apt purge synaptic ; sudo apt install synaptic` to reinstall it and then try again. If that doesn't help, the only advice I personally can give you is to file a bug report on Launchpad. Also please [edit] your question and include the output you just posted there, so that it doesn't get lost in the comments.

Comment: What happens if you [switch to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) from the default Wayland one?

Answer (score 1):

Switching to an Xorg session allowed me to successfully run Synaptic. However, Synaptic didn't succeed in properly installing Zotero, so that remains a problem.

Comment: You're welcome to [open a new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question.