# Ubuntu 17.10 - portrait monitor showing extra arrow

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 17.10

I recently hooked-up a second monitor to an Nvidia GEFORCE GTX 1060.
When I am using my primary monitor, the secondary monitor shows the cursor as well.

My monitor setup:

- Left monitor portrait _____ 1200x1920 (secondary)
- Right monitor landscape __  1920x1200 (primary)

with the Ubuntu desktop.

In particular, when my cursor is in the top-left 1/6th of the primary landscape monitor, I see the cursor in the bottom-left 1/6th of my secondary portrait monitor. But, if I am in that same bottom-left 1/6th of the secondary portrait monitor, I do not see it in the primary landscape monitor.

Note: I have already tried using the proprietary and Nouveau open-source driver, and this unfortunately did not solve the issue.

Comment: have you checked whether your monitors overlap?

Comment: @ravery They don't, but when I was checking this a second ago, if I make the portrait monitor be on the right side of the primary landscape one, then I don't have this problem. Strange.

Comment: @pomsky Thank for the hint. This seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: @pomsky Should we report this somehow?

Comment: @Janusz Bugs should be reported at launchpad. Try here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a yet-another-issue-with-Wayland.

As a workaround you may switch back to Xorg from the default Wayland session following this Q&A: [How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)