# How to enable scrolling with Wacom touch strips and Gnome Shell?

Tags: wacom, gnome-shell, wayland, input

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 with Gnome Shell and a Wacom Intuos 3. The tablet has a vertical touch strip on either side and I would like to use these for vertical scrolling.

`xsetwacom` reports that these strips are both configured by default to send vertical mouse scroll button signals:

```
> xsetwacom --get -s "Wacom Intuos3 6x8 Pad pad" all | grep Strip
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos3 6x8 Pad pad" "StripLeftUp" "1" "button +4 "
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos3 6x8 Pad pad" "StripLeftDown" "2" "button +5 "
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos3 6x8 Pad pad" "StripRightUp" "3" "button +4 "
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos3 6x8 Pad pad" "StripRightDown" "4" "button +5 "
```

But the GUI system settings for the Wacom tablet show that the buttons are configured to have no effect. My understanding is that some piece of software is swallowing the mouse scroll signals coming from the tablet and not passing them to the system.

[image]

I have tried various ways to get the tablet to emit `F13` and `F14` keys with the intention of remapping these to scroll signals at a system level. However, none of my attempts work:

```
> xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos3 6x8 Pad pad" StripLeftUp key F13
Warning: unable to map 'F13' to a keycode.

> xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos3 6x8 Pad pad" StripLeftUp key 0xffca
Warning: unable to map '0xffca' to a keycode.

> xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos3 6x8 Pad pad" StripLeftUp key XK_F13
Invalid key 'XK_F13'.
Cannot parse keyword 'XK_F13' at position 2
```

What can I do to stop the system from intercepting scroll signals or send them by other means using these touch strips?

Comment: What happens if you attempt those methods after [switching to an Xorg session from the default Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)?

Comment: Scrolling works in an Xorg session. Lots of other things seem to be broken though :)

Answer (score 0):

To stop gnome from intercepting Wacom pad events you could try this:

1. [Switch to Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)
2. Run `dconf-editor`
3. navigate to `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.gsdwacom`
4. set this value to false

Comment: I've disabled `gsd-wacom` as suggested but scrolling still doesn't work. Also, I can still see two `gsd-wacom` processes running (one owned by user `gdm` and one owned by me).

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question, I thought you had already switched to Xorg (xsetwacom only works with Xorg).

Comment: @pomsky I will do, we could also Wayland to the question and then delete my answer

Comment: I would suggest against deleting the answer. OP (and others) may find it useful.

Comment: this gsd entry does not affect the gsd-wacom process at all. Somehow it is still in effective.

Comment: FYI, https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/issues/118 you cannot switch it off anymore