# Launcher Missing on Ubuntu 17.10 after installing Cairo Dock

Tags: 17.10, compiz, ubuntu-dock

I'm kinda new in Linux environment. I installed Ubuntu and play along with some modifications. Recently I tried installing Cairo-Dock and didn't like it so I decided to remove it afterwards. But then, once I finished uninstalling and reboot my system, my launcher (Ubuntu Dock) is suddenly disappeared.

[image: Screenshot-1]

I wanted to restore it back by reinstalling the `unity-desktop`, removing compiz config, and enabling Ubuntu Unity Plugin thing.. all didn't work. And now I'm desperately wanting to get my launcher back and ended up having no idea what to do any more.

[image: Screenshot-2]

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Where did you get the idea of reinstalling `unity-desktop` and compizconfig? Ubuntu 17.10 has GNOME, not Unity. No wonder those solutions failed.

Comment: Try (re-)installing `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` package instead.

Comment: @pomsky ya, my bad. i was so desperate that i just followed all the instructions i found online.

Comment: Try my suggestion above. But I reckon your computer will be in a messy state with two desktop environments now. I would suggest you to do a fresh installation of Ubuntu if you can afford do it.

Comment: @pomsky i managed to get everything back. but now my ubuntu 17.10 looks like ubuntu 16 interface. any idea on how to make it back to 17.10 interface?

Comment: That's because you've installed `unity-desktop` and I believe you have now logged in a Unity session instead of a GNOME session. Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/961345/480481) and select "Ubuntu" or "GNOME" instead of "Unity". But once again I would recommend a fresh installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, i managed to solve all of these by resetting dconf and reinstalling gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock (thanks to @pomsky).