# How to boot into 'Ubuntu on Xorg' by default?

Tags: unity, xorg, environment

Unity runs like a lame donkey on my laptop, yet flies when I switch to Xorg. Is there a way to set it to use this by default without having to log out and in again every time?

Comment: See the [answer by Sam Thomas](https://askubuntu.com/a/968265/527764)