# windows in background flicker in 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10

If I have multiple windows open in the gnome desktop, I see the border (title bar + scroll bar) of the hidden window occasionally flicker through the window I'm looking at. Not sure if anyone knows what would cause this. I didn't have this problem with gnome in 16.04. I've tried multiple nvidia drivers as well as nouveau, all with the same issue, so I'm assuming this is a gnome/ubuntu thing. The problem seems to occur most frequently when I move a window from one monitor to the next in a multimonitor setup. Should I be turning off extensions or animations or something?

Comment: Try [switching back to Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) if you're in a Wayland session and see what happens there.

Comment: this didn't do it, though it seemed promising for a few minutes

Comment: It seems relevant that the issue seems to occur when moving a window from one monitor to the next in a multimonitor setup. I'm adding this to the statement.