# AnyDesk won't screenshare on Ubuntu

Tags: screen

When I show my friend my screenshare in anydesk, he claims it's a black screen, fully black screen, and I can't get it to work for some reason, even in Discord screensharing, help me.. Also the version of Ubuntu is 17.10

Comment: [Switch to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) if you're in a Wayland session and try.

Comment: One more thing, switching to xorg session gave me a system program error...