# MacBook Pro 14,1 with Ubuntu 17.10 - Second display not working on dock

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, display, macbook, macbook-pro

I installed Kubuntu 17.10 on my MacBook Pro 14,1 and made some adjustments (mostly enabling kernel modules) to make the basics work fine.

Now I would like to be able to plug my second display in a dock, but that doesn't work.

When I plug the USB-C cable of my second display directly into the mac, it works fine, the screen is detected and turns on, but when I plug it on the USB-C port of a dock that is plugged in the mac, nothing happens.

I just tried on another mac (same model) that still has MacOS, and it works. I also tried with another dock that has a power supply, and on my Linux, it works.

- Tested on 2 docks without a power supply, doesn't work on Linux but works on MacOS.
- Tested on 1 dock with a power supply, works both on Linux and MacOS.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 is end of life, you should use a supported version.

Comment: What do you mean "end of life"?

Comment: It's not supported any more, and hence [off-topic here](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). Currently supported releases are: 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS, and 17.10. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will arrive in a week or so.

Comment: Oh my bad, I do have the version 17.10. I edited.

Comment: Was the MacOS removed from the system?  If not, have you tried with the dock in the MacOS to eliminate the hardware as being the problem?

Comment: It was indeed removed. We have several other computers that are exactly the same as mine at work, though, so I can try with the same docks on another one. Will try monday!

Comment: @Terrance Just added the test cases and their results in the post.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't have the matching equipment so I won't be able to duplicate your issue to fully help you out.  I can suggest though that maybe try to login into the system using XOrg.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10  Maybe the dock doesn't like Wayland.

Comment: @Terrance I don't seem to have this option.  I have this screen, in which I don't find how to go on XOrg: https://news-cdn.softpedia.com/images/news2/kde-plasma-5-10-desktop-environment-to-ship-with-virtual-keyboard-on-lock-screen-513765-2.jpg

Comment: My bad!  I just read it again about you installed Kubuntu and not Ubuntu.  Kubuntu doesn't have it installed.  If it works with the power connected to the dock then you might have to use power supplies for it.  Why that makes a difference, I don't know unless somehow the MacOS is controlling the hardware differently for where the voltage goes.

Comment: Okay I just received a new dock with a power supply and in fact it doesn't work either? I checked again the dock on which it worked, and the screen was connected through the display port of the dock, while I connect mine through the USB-C port of the dock.