# Horizontal bars on display

Tags: drivers, nvidia, wayland

Late last year I upgraded my desktop with an Asus GeForce 8800GTX board, and installed 2 displays.  All was working fine for months, but late last year at start-up Ubuntu boots to horizontal white and black bars.  No sign-on screen.  I also upgraded to an AsRock AB350 board and Ryzen 3 1300X cpu.  I attempted multiple fixes to Nvidia drivers from the forums without success.  Will the Nvidia -Wayland conflict be corrected with Ubuntu 18.04?

At the moment I have reverted back to Windows until I am confident that Ubuntu (any flavor) will work with my current hardware configuration.  Are there any other fixes I can do?

Comment: 18.04 will be defaulting back to XOrg instead of Wayland but it will have both installed.  Until then, have you tried using Ubuntu 17.10 with XOrg?  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10

Comment: My installation of 17.10 is not showing an Xorg option.  I will hold for 18.04.