# Applications won't allow keyboard input untill they are restarted

Tags: keyboard, 17.10, ubuntu-gnome

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10.

When I start an application such as terminal or Firefox, they often (not always) will not do anything on any key-press. This is fixed by closing and opening the window, or a new tab in the terminal.

Is there a more permanent solution to this?

Comment: Sorry, checked version number when adding tags and forgot I wrote it up top. I've changed the post. I am actually on 17.10

Comment: Did you test it on Windows? That could rule out a hardware problem.

Comment: Yeah, I have a dualboot set up to windows and I've never had a problem with it on Windows.

Comment: Did you also try it booting from a LiveCD with another Linux distro (or even the same, maybe is a specific package)?

Comment: It worked fine on Ubuntu 16 so it might be some issue with gnome?

Comment: I suppose it has been upgraded from Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 17.10, could you try booting a Ubuntu 17.10 liveCD and test how it works?

Comment: Try [switching back to Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) if you're in a default Wayland session.

Comment: Switching to Xorg didn't fix it, neither did a live cd