# Cannot run Ubuntu 18.04 on Xorg

Tags: boot, xorg, desktop-environments, 18.04, wayland

My ideapad y520 was running Ubuntu 17.04 and recently I updated it to 18.04 from command line. However, I'm not able to boot into any desktop environment in Xorg mode. Only Wayland is working. Has anyone faced similar issue?

Comment: Note to **"Unclear" Close Voters:** The question is clear to me.

Comment: Duplicate with no votes so can't close: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029384/can-not-start-xorg-after-upgrade-ubuntu-to-18-04

Comment: Upgrading from 17.04 to 18.04 LTS is not likely to succeed. It is probably difficult to fix the problems. Try live, when booted from a USB pendrive made from an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS iso file. If it works well, please **save your personal files to another drive** and after that [maybe convert your original partition from the old 17.04 to a home partition and] make a fresh installation of 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you switch from Wayland back to Xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10)

Answer (score 4):

I had to uncomment 'WaylandEnable=false' in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf to be able to boot up.  It worked, but I'd like to find a better fix for the situation.  Booting up with 'WaylandEnable=false' commented out I would get stuck at gdm.servicegdm.service.

I hope this helps someone, I looked for this for a couple weeks.

Comment: I was having graphical glitches upon login in gdm3 on a MacBookPro12,1 running 18.04 with Xorg. Un-commenting the line above made this glitch go away.