# Can not start Xorg after upgrade Ubuntu to 18.04

Tags: boot, xorg, 18.04

After upgrade Ubuntu to 18.04 (from 17.10), Xorg is unable to start. It just repeatedly switches between black and grey blank screens. I reconfigured the grub to boot in text mode with nomodeset. The startx command was unable to start the Xorg server. I have a built-in Intel graphic card. Here is the output of the /var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
[    38.698] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event10)
[    38.698] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    38.698] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    38.698] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event11)
[    38.698] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    38.699] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    38.699] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic (/dev/input/event5)
[    38.699] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    38.699] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    38.699] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Mic (/dev/input/event6)
[    38.699] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    38.699] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    38.699] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line (/dev/input/event7)
[    38.699] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    38.699] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    38.700] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line Out (/dev/input/event8)
[    38.700] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    38.700] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    38.700] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone (/dev/input/event9)
[    38.700] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    38.700] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    41.427] (**) Option "fd" "21"
[    41.427] (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
[    41.427] (**) Option "fd" "24"
[    41.427] (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
[    41.427] (**) Option "fd" "25"
[    41.427] (II) event2  - PixArt USB Optical Mouse: device removed
[    41.427] (**) Option "fd" "26"
[    41.427] (II) event3  -   USB Keyboard: device removed
[    41.427] (**) Option "fd" "27"
[    41.427] (II) event4  -   USB Keyboard: device removed
[    41.428] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    41.428] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:68
[    41.444] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    41.444] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:67
[    41.460] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    41.460] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:66
[    41.512] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    41.512] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:64
[    41.528] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    41.528] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:65
[    41.653] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

output from grep "(EE)" /var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
[    86.288] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    86.289] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    86.289] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    86.294] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
```

Comment: Grep the log for (EE)

Comment: @mreff555 updated in description.

Comment: Make sure your i915 drivers weren’t uninstalled after the upgrade. I don’t know exactly what Ubuntu calls this package, just search for intel video drivers.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I got the same issue !!!

Comment: I didn't find any solution, so I reinstalled the system completely.